# Euclidean distance calculation using apache flink

Tags: java, apache-flink, euclidean-distance

Apache flink has setup libraries to calculate euclidean distance. I want to use the same API for distance calculation on n-dimensional space. I have two dataset with 3 features.

> a = {0.1,0.3,0.8}
>   b = {0.2,0.4,0.7}

How can I calculate the distance between both this vectors using apache flink.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
final ExecutionEnvironment env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

final DataSet<double[]> a = env.fromElements(new double[]{0.1, 0.3, 0.8});
final DataSet<double[]> b = env.fromElements(new double[]{0.2, 0.4, 0.7});

a.cross(b).map(new MapFunction<Tuple2<double[],double[]>, Double>() {

    final EuclideanDistance distance = new EuclideanDistance();

    @Override
    public Double map(Tuple2<double[], double[]> value) throws Exception {
        return distance.compute(value.f0, value.f1);
    }
})
.print(); // start execution and output result to STDOUT
```

Here I used `org.apache.commons.math3.ml.distance.EuclideanDistance` to calculate the distance.